# JQuery in Struts1.x

Tags: jquery, struts-1

I am using `LookupdispatchAction` in struts 1.x. I want to call a method `getData` in `Action` class using JQuery ajax call `Struts-config` file. Below is my JSP code where I am using three buttons. When I click on the get button, then struts `getdata` method should be called through ajax call.

```
  <html>
    <head>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        var popup1 = false;

        function openPopUp(id) {
        }
      </script>

    </head>
    <body bgcolor="skyblue">

      <html:form action="/Appointment">
        <table>
          <tr><td><html:errors /></td></tr>
          <tr><td>PatientName:<html:text property="PatientName" /></td></tr>
          <tr><td>Time:<html:text property="Time" /></td></tr>
          <tr><td>INTime:<html:text property="INTime" /></td></tr>
          <tr><td>DoctorName:<html:text property="DoctorName" /></td></tr>
          <tr><td><html:submit property="method" value="register" /></td></tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input type="button" onclick="openPopUp('popup1')" value="get" />
              <div id="popup1" class="popup"></div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr><td><html:submit property="method" value="delete" /></td></tr>
        </table>
      </html:form>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Struts-config file

```
<struts-config>
  <form-beans>
    <form-bean name="dynaRegistrationForm" type="org.apache.struts.action.DynaActionForm">

      <form-property name="PatientName" type="java.lang.String" />
      <form-property name="Time" type="java.lang.String" />
      <form-property name="INTime" type="java.lang.String" />
      <form-property name="DoctorName" type="java.lang.String" />

    </form-bean>
  </form-beans>

  <action-mappings>
    <action type="doctor.Appointing"
            name="dynaRegistrationForm"
            path="/Appointment"
            input="/Apoint.jsp" parameter="method" scope="request">
      <forward name="success" path="/Apoint.jsp" />
    </action>
  </action-mappings>

  <message-resources parameter="apps"/>

</struts-config>
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: I want to know how to call a method in Action class (iam using Lookup dispatch action) using Ajax call.

Comment: An action is mapped to a URL. Send an AJAX request to this URL, and the actio will be called.

Comment: Calling Struts 1 through jQuery is no different than calling anything else through jQuery. What specific issue with jQuery are you having?

Answer (score 0):

You should call the URL "/Appointment" with your ajax call. Add the following in your openPopUp(id) javascript function which gets called when you click your "get" button.

```
function openPopUp(id) {
    $.get("Appointment.do", function(data){
          //do what you want with data. 
    });
}
```